# Can't change background on a footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the background of my footer dark grey.  Here's the HTML:

```
<footer>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col span-1-of-2">
            <ul class="footer-nav">
                <li><a href="#">XYZ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">XYZ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">XYZ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">XYZ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">XYZ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col span-1-of-2">
            <ul class="social-links">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-twitter icon-small"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-facebook icon-small"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-instagram icon-small"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-google icon-small"></i></a></li>
            
            </ul>
        </div>
      
    </div>
</footer>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
footer {
background-color: #555;}
```

I think it's because the information in the two divs is covering up the footer.  However, I've tried giving the divs their own class names and using the 'inherit' property and it hasn't worked.  If anyone could give me some advice I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: If you don't care at all about the background color of those `divs`, just make them transparent (ie: `background: none` or `background-color: transparent`). The same applies to their children elements, if they also have a background set.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm afraid it's still not working.  I gave the two lists class names of 'left-hand-links' and 'right-hand-links' respectively.  Then I used the following CSS:

.

footer { background: #555; }
left-hand-links { background: none; }
right-hand-links {background: none; }

.

but nothing happened.  I then tried:

.

footer { background-color: #555; }
left-hand-links { background-color: transparent; }
right-hand-links {background-color: transparent; }

but that didn't work either.

Comment: I would have thought that this would suffice: `footer > * { background: none; }`

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work either.  I changed the CSS to:

footer { background: #555; } 

and then added

footer > * { background: none; }

but the problem still remains.

Comment: If you inspect those elements on the browser dev tools, what styling can you see? If you don't know what's and how's applied it's gonna be a lottery trying to override them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an "important" to the rule setting the background-color of the footer and you're set to fly:

```
<style type="text/css">
  footer, footer div {
        background-color: #555 !important;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: This should be the last resort. Probably just if you're trying to apply styles to elements that come from a 3rd part library and it would cause you havoc to try to change their stylesheets.

Comment: Hi.  I tried this and it worked without the '!important' modifier.  It's weird though.  I'd have thought that using the 'inherit' property would've done the same thing but it didn't.  Anyway, it's fixed now.  Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: I suppose the 'footer div' selector is doing the trick.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Hi there! When I put only the code you provide to us in here http://www.play-hookey.com/htmltest/ A grey footer is created. I can only conclude that another command is overriding yours. The easiest way to fix this is by making it important

```css
 footer, footer{
        background-color: #555 !important;
  }
```

This is however, bad practice, and you should troubleshoot before doing that

Troubleshooting

1. Try putting your footer styling below all other styling, the browser might be reading something else and overwriting your code
2. Its not good practice but you could use inline styling
3. Or you can create a class and apply it to your footer, as those rank above styling the element

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I've fixed the issue now, but even after looking through my code I'm still not sure what caused it.  I think it must've been a specificity issue because, although giving the footer a class or an ID didn't help, the issue resolved when I used inline styling.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might sound silly, but if you are running it on your browser to check, May I suggest deleting your browsing history?

I've had issues in the past which make my head scratch only to realize the solution is solved after I delete my browsing history (mainly the **cache**).

Comment: you can press ctrl+shift+f5 to do this, by the way

Answer (score -1):

Unable to comment but I will provide this link where it is working as expected.

```css
footer {
    background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col span-1-of-2">
            <ul class="footer-nav">
                <li><a href="#">XYZ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">XYZ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">XYZ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">XYZ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">XYZ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col span-1-of-2">
            <ul class="social-links">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-twitter icon-small"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-facebook icon-small"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-instagram icon-small"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-google icon-small"></i></a></li>
            
            </ul>
        </div>
      
    </div>
</footer>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mattbhenley/pen/eYzmmQV)